# Architectural comments for queueing with RabbitMQ?

Tags: architecture, erlang, queue, rabbitmq, message-queue

I basically need a queueing technology that will enable to queue messages. These messages will then later be transmitted as SMS texts. RabbitMQ seems to be quite a good fit after I glossed over the apis.

My current architecture plans:

1. clients queue messages in RabbitMQ.
2. Another daemon will reads messages off RabbitMQ and sends those off to a 3rd party SMS gateway. The daemon should be able to spawn multiple listener threads.
3. I plan to host everything on slicehost.com using an Ubuntu Hardy.

Do you forsee any problems with this design? Since I have cursory knowledge of Erlang, I have no ideas on how to run it in a production environment. If you have any experience with Erlang or RabbitMQ, I'd like to hear your war stories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Erlang war stories, a few good ones were given at this year's Commercial Users of Functional Programming (CUFP) workshop in Victoria:

[Developing Erlang At Yahoo](http://cufp.galois.com/2008/slides/GerakinesNick.pdf)

[Ad Serving in Erlang](http://cufp.galois.com/2008/slides/IppolitoBob/slides.html)

And at the Erlang Workshop the following day:

[Imperative and Functional Implementations of the IMAP Protocol](http://www.erlang.org/workshop/2008/Sess21.pdf)

The feeling from the workshops was that, while by no means mainstream, Erlang has now spread sufficiently among startups and large companies, that using it for commercial gain can be seen as a rather safe bet. About half the companies present at the Erlang workshop were hiring.

Check out the [erlang.org](http://www.erlang.org) website and especially the [Erlang mailing list](http://www.erlang.org/mailman/listinfo/erlang-questions). It houses all types, from newbies to seasoned professionals.